# Python try/expect code shows `local variable referenced before assignment` error

Tags: python

I added this code here meant for error handling:

```
try:
    music = session.query(Music).filter_by(Assetid=id).one()
    music.firstname = new_AssetName
    music.lastname = new_category
    music.DOB = new_borrower
    music.experience = new_status
    music.experience = new_value
    session.commit()
except Exception as e:
   message = "Error updating player:" + e.toString()  
finally:
    return template('success.tpl', message=message)
```

and it keeps on giving me the error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to make message a global variable so like:

```
except Exception as e:
   global message
   message = "Error updating player:" + e.toString()
```

But this just gives me an error saying that message is not defined.
I am quite lost on how to fix this any help would be great

Comment: You try block doesn't have message variable. If no error occurs in try block, finally block would throw exception because it cannot find message variable (since it was never declared in try block or before it). finally block runs regardless of whether try runs or except block runs successfully. See docs for how finally block works. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Comment: Pro-tip for future projects; try to avoid `global` at all costs. It can and will make debugging an absolute nightmare and is very rarely needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **message** variable is not defined in your **try** block. This means that when your code gets to the **finally** block, if the execution didn't raise an exception the **message** variable will be undefined and therefore raise the **UnboundLocalError** exception.

To solve this, you could simply do:

```
try:
    music = session.query(Music).filter_by(Assetid=id).one()
    music.firstname = new_AssetName
    music.lastname = new_category
    music.DOB = new_borrower
    music.experience = new_status
    music.experience = new_value
    session.commit()
    message = "Successfully updated player"

except Exception as e:
    message = f"Error updating player: {e}"

finally:
    return template("success.tpl", message=message)
```